# Thinset too dry before laying tile? Not dry enough?

Tags: tile, mortar, tiling, thinset, porcelain

Yesterday I laid 6x36 wood-look porcelain tile in my bedroom using a mapei ultraflex LFT thinset directly to the concrete slab. It's been 24 hours, and I am now pulling off the top tab of the spacers for the wedge tile leveling system I used.

When I pulled on the top tab for a shorter tile, the tile popped right off the floor. I could see that the thinset was very weak, it had a powdery and crumbly consistency, I could scrape it off the floor and the back of the tile very easily.

It was still kind of wet, so perhaps I did not wait long enough to allow it to dry, but I am concerned that this tile is an indicator that any tile that I placed using that same bucket of thinset will also pop off very easily.

My question is this, what may have caused the thin set to be so weak? If I allow it to dry will it become strong? Is it better to remove the potentially impacted tiles now and scrape the thinset off while it's still pliable?

[image]

Comment: It should set (chemical reaction) not "dry" - how did you mix it? Did you precisely measure water (or additive, if using an additive) and mortar (you refer to bucket, which caused me to think premix, but the product name is leading to bagged dry mortar mix when I search.) You can [edit] that information into your question.

Comment: Looks like you didn't scrape the paint/primer off the concrete before tiling.  It looks dry to me.

Comment: Did you backbutter the tiles and burn in the thinset on the surface before troweling? What size trowel? How long was the thinset mixed prior to using on this section?

Comment: "I pulled on the top tab." - don't do that. You smack 'em sideways and break them with the rubber mallet that you set the tiles with (*that you set the tiles with*, right?... *Right!?!*) while standing on the two tiles it touches. - You'll find out in three days, which is as soon as you can grout it anyway, when you tap on them and they sound hollow.

Comment: @redlude97 I've heard of back buttering, but what's "burn in the thinset"? Not a term I'm familiar with. Share a link?

Comment: @Mazura clarity please, is a hollow sound a _good_ thing or a _bad_ thing?

Comment: @FreeMan its simply using the straightside of the trowel to spread around the thinset before troweling in the lines. It helps to pick up and mix in the little bit of dust and debris right on the surface and also helps a little bit with that initial drying of the thinset when the moisture gets sucked into the substrate

https://floorelf.com/how-to-install-tile-on-a-shower-ceiling/comment-page-8

Comment: If it sounds hollow there's air in there and you didn't get +85% adhesion (some tile does just sound wack tho). Large format tile must be back buttered. And it must be 'set' right. You're supposed to move it back and forth like an 1/8", then tap it with a rubber mallet all over. Do that to a tile and then try to pull it up; it will suction cup. If you're lucky, maybe it's just a little bad by the wall, and you went at it too soon, and wrongly.

Comment: Cool, @redlude97, I didn't know that it had a name, but I did that just because it made sense to me.

Comment: Thanks, @Mazura, that's helpful info.

Comment: You're supposed to 'burn' the floor first too, then trowel the lines. I'd say *burning* is scraping it flat, *back buttering* is burnt-on then lined, but it's really all the same thing with the same goal: +85% contact.